# Problem with java-doc for standard java library

Tags: java, linux, netbeans, ubuntu, javadoc

I recently started using Ubuntu and installed netbeans 6.9.1. I seem to be missing some javadocs tho that get installed with the windows version.

Basically the netbeans docs are there but when the code completion comes up it only tells me the function prototype. Where theres usually a description it says that the javadocs are not found and they should be added in the platform or library manager.

Basically I just want the docs explaining the methods for basic java, swing, and awt. Anyone know what files it is i want to be getting, and can I do it all with apt-get?

OS:
Ubuntu 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem. Solution is very simple:

You have to download "Java SE 6 Documentation" from this page (in Additional Resources list)
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

It is a zip file (~50 mb). Put this file to some place you like(I suggest you to put it to the JDK directory, but you can put it to your home directory) and then open NetBeans.

Select Tools -> Java Platforms. Then select JDK on the left window. In the Javadoc tab, click Add ZIP/Folder and choose file you recently download.

When you done this, your javadoc in code completition windows will work correctly.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you have not installed java-doc package:

```
sudo apt-get install sun-java6-doc
```

or what ever is suitable for you.